# Cannot find name Promise Angular2

Tags: angular

I'm new to this and I'm following a tutorial. My code is verbatim from the tutorial video which is working, but my code isn't. I'm getting the error "Cannot find name 'Promise' and I can't figure out why. Does anyone have an idea of why i'm getting this error?

```
import {Control} from 'angular2/common'

export class UsernameValidators{
static shouldBeUnique(control: Control){

return new Promise ((resolve) => {

setTimeout(function(){
  if(control.value == "andy")
  resolve({shouldBeUnique: true})
else
resolve(null);
}, 1000);

});

}
  static cannotContainSpace(control: Control){
if (control.value.indexOf(' ') >=0)
return {cannotContainSpace: true};
return null;

  }
}
```

Comment: Are you targeting ES6 in your tsconfig?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using a beta version of Angular2.  The following answer assumes you are using:

```json
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
```

Provided you are using Angular 2.0.0 or later, you can do the following:

```ts
import { FormControl } from "@angular/forms";
import { Promise } from "./path/to/node_modules/es6-promise";

export class UsernameValidators {
    static shouldBeUnique(control: FormControl) {

        return new Promise((resolve) => {

            setTimeout(function () {
                if (control.value === "andy")
                    resolve({ shouldBeUnique: true });
                else
                    resolve(null);
            }, 1000);

        });

    }
    static cannotContainSpace(control: FormControl) {
        if (control.value.indexOf(" ") >= 0)
            return { cannotContainSpace: true };
        return null;

    }
}
```

Comment: I think you're right about the beta version. That would explain it. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are experience cannot find name 'Promise'., mostly you have changed some files in the base setup or may be you didn't finish the node package installation successfully. Angular2 doesn't use `typings` package anymore.

solution:

- clone the following repository https://github.com/angular/quickstart
- run `npm install` in the project directory and make sure it finish successfully
- now copy and config your app project folders into the cloned new folder
  now this will work perfectly.